# What do the various forehead dots and marks signify?

Tags: practice, culture, tilak, symbols

I currently live in an area which has a high Indian population. I've noticed a number of Indian men and women with various marks and dots on their foreheads but have never asked about the significance behind these for fear of offending them. I genuinely want to know what they mean.

Here's what I've seen:

- A single black dot (quite small)
- A single red dot (quite small)
- A single red dot (much larger)
- A single red dot (smudged and near the hairline)
- A yellow vertical line
- A white vertical line
- A white vertical line with hairline red dot

What do these all mean, and are there others that I may not be aware of?

I guess I'm more wondering if there is a more *modern* context to these markings than the "third-eye" or channeling chakras, etc.?

Comment: duplicate of http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/163/why-hindus-wear-red-tilak-and-sandal-wood-tilak-on-foreheads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different types of *tilaka* colors signify different aspects.

For instance Skandamahāpurāṇam Verse 2.5.2.30 says the following -

> [Chapter 2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371681.html), Mārgaśīrṣa-māhātmya, Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa, Skanda-purāṇa
>
> श्यामं शांतिकरं प्रोक्तं रक्तं वश्यकरं तथा ।
>  श्रीकरं पीतमित्याहुः
> श्वेतं मोक्षकरं शुभम् ॥ ३० ॥
>
> > 30. **A dark-coloured Tilaka is said to be conducive to peace; a red one is the cause of winning over others. They say that a yellow one is
> >     conducive to prosperity and glory. A white one brings about salvation
> >     and is auspicious.**

The specific [varying shapes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilaka#/media/File%3AExamples_of_Tilaks_or_sect-marks.jpg) of the *Tilaka*, like 'the U shaped (Urdhvapuṇdra)' , or 'three vertical lines (Tripuṇḍra)' or the '[red-dots](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50788/does-the-red-dot-tilaka-of-the-%C5%9A%C4%81ktas-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4-have-any-name) (bindu)', are basically sectarian markings of different sects within Hinduism like Vaishnavas, Shaivas, Shaktas, and so on.