# Does the 'Red-dot' Tilaka of the Śāktas (शाक्त) have any name?

Tags: shakti, shaktism, tilak

For Instance:

- The name of the Tilaka worn by the Śaivas (शैव) is [Tripuṇḍra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripundra) Tilaka (त्रिपुण्ड्र-तिलक).
- The name of the Tilaka worn by the Vaiṣṇavas (वैष्णव) is [Ūrdhvapuṇḍra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdhva_Pundra) Tilaka (ऊर्ध्वपुण्ड्र-तिलक).

The Śāktas (शाक्त) are generally known to wear a [red-dot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Examples_of_Tilaks_or_sect-marks.jpg) as their Tilaka.

> [image]

##### Is there any dedicated name of the tilaka worn by the Śāktas (शाक्त)?

Or the 'red-dot' is simply called Bindu?

Comment: I have heard it being called boonda

Answer (score 3):

It's simply called Vartulakar Tilak (वर्तुलाकार तिलक) or Mandalakar tilak (मण्डलाकार तिलक) owing to it's circular shape.

So Shri Shri Bhaskararay Ji, while commenting on Shri Kaulopnisad's Sutras. Says,

> अन्त: शाक्तः । बहिः शैवः । लोके वैष्णवः । अयमेवाचारः ।
> A Kaul is Shakta internally, a Shaiv externally and a Vaishnav in Public.

Shri Raya says:-

> अप्राकट्येऽपि कर्त्तव्यतामेव विवृणोति ।                 शक्तरूपास्तिरन्तःकरणेकवेद्या कार्या।
> Here the Duty to keep the Achar Secret is described, He is a Shakta by his heart.

> कुचन्दनेन शाक्तानां भ्रमध्ये **बिन्दुरिष्यते**।
> इति चिह्नानि विदितान्यपि
> Shakta smears Chandan Paste on forehead and **Bindu** between eyebrows, this is the symbol prescribed.

> विभूतिधारणादि शैवाचिह्नराच्छादितान्ये व कार्याणि ।
> Or one should hide the **Red Maha Bindu** under Shaiva Symbols like Vibhuti.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. Visit [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn more and edit by adding authentic sources.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto already done. Hope the tag be removed now.

Comment: great, thanks! You can always notify us via "flag" option for banner removal or anything which doesn't look good. Ping me in chat if you need help on main site: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism

Comment: Sure, thanks to let me know. Indebted...

Answer (score 0):

According to Radhatantram.:

> त्रिपुण्डं धारयेत्‌ शैव: **शाक्तश्न वर्तुलं** शिवे । ऊर्ध्वपुण्डूं गाणपत्य: साधकस्यापि लक्षणम्‌ ॥
>
> The characteristics of a saint are Tripundra by Shaiva , **Vartula by Shakta,** Urdhva Pundra by Ganapatya.

I hope this helps. Prd..