# Does the Gāṇapatyas (गाणपत्य) and the Sauras (सौर) have any dedicated sectarian Tilaka?

Tags: ganesha, surya, tilak, pancayatana, smarta

Each sect/subsect within Hinduism has its own dedicated 'sectarian holy markings" known as Tilaka (तिलक).

For Instance:

- The Śaivaites (शैव) - the worshippers of god Śiva as the Supreme, wears the [Tripuṇḍra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripundra) Tilaka (त्रिपुण्ड्र-तिलक).
- The Śāktas (शाक्त) - the worshippers of the great goddess Parā-Śakti as the Supreme, wears a red dot ([Bindu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50788/does-the-red-dot-tilaka-of-the-%C5%9A%C4%81ktas-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4-have-any-name)) as their Tilaka.
- The Vaiṣṇavas (वैष्णव) - the worshipper of god Viṣṇu (or Kṛṣṇa or Rāma, etc.) as the Supreme, wears the [Ūrdhvapuṇḍra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdhva_Pundra) Tilaka (ऊर्ध्वपुण्ड्र-तिलक) or it's sub-variations.

There are two other deities viz. Gaṇeśa & Sūrya with their own dedicated sects - Gāṇapatyas (गाणपत्य) and Sauras (सौर), respectively. Together these five deities form the part of the [Pañcāyatana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/pancayatana) (पञ्चायतन) or Pañcāyatanapūjā form of worship, which is specifically observed by the followers of the [Smārta tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarta_tradition) (स्मार्तधर्म).

---

In any case, the three out of the five deities of the  Pañcāyatana - Śiva, Śakti & Viṣṇu have their own dedicated Tilakas for their sects.

##### Do the sects of the other two deities (Gaṇeśa & Sūrya) have their dedicated Tilakas?

##### What *Tilakas* do the Gāṇapatyas (गाणपत्य) and the Sauras (सौर) wear?

What is the name of Tilakas worn by the Gāṇapatyas and Sauras?

Comment: Ganapatya wear urdhva pundra see last part of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44949/21353) answer.

Comment: Yeah, I read your answer way back, @Proxy .... But, I think the problem is more like Brahmâ's tilaka, because in various depictions we can find huge variations. For instance - See [this image chart](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/348254983679783028/) & [this image chart](https://m.facebook.com/424910937646895/posts/another-set-of-tilaks-of-ganapatya-sect-thanks-to-mario-sabato-for-this-amazing-/1331666503637996/). There seems a bigger variation in case of Gāṇapatyas.

Comment: Nice! Lets see if someone has got more details on this.