# Red Tilak worn by Hindu women

Tags: shiva, tilak

I have not learned about Hindu culture but it hurts me when some people say that the tilak worn by Hindu women and men is a curse of Lord Shiva to people who laughed at him when Ganga menstruated on his forehead! Is this true?

Comment: This is false. Tilak is related to Agna Chakra and nothing to do with Shiva's curse.

Comment: I've tried answering this in original question. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11421/73

Comment: @TheDestroyer Agnya Chakra is related to Kriya Yoga which is not part of Original Vedanta or mimansakas. So Kriya yoga is part of Sankya or Yoga School of thought which is improper according to Veda vyasa. So it concludes that the Authentic Sanatana Dharma dosen't contain anything like Kundalini or Kriya yoga it is later additions. The true form of Yoga is Bhakti Which is mix of Karma, jana Yoga as Discussed in Shrimad Bhagwad Gita.

Comment: @Yogi If one sage doesn't like one particular school, then it doesn't mean that school of thought is incorrect. "Authentic Santana Dharma"? Vedas are main essence of Santana Dharma. Based on teachings of Vedas, Nastika Schools were formed. You can't completely say Samkya school of thought as incorrect and term only teachings of Vyasa or Bhagavatam as Authentic. Who said Bhakti yoga is true form of Yoga? Do you know how difficult other paths of Yoga are? Karma Yoga is best Yoga according to me. it depends on temperament of person.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Veda Vyasa is not just one Sage he is intellectual Giant of This MahaYuga. He compiled Vedas, and most important of all he is incarnation of Shri Hari Vishnu. Since `Vedas are main Essence of Hinduism/Sanatana Dharma` then Vyasa is like The Greatest Rishi for this Mahayuga and since he compiled whole vedas he also wrote commentry on the essence of Essence of Hinduism(Vedas) Known as bramha Sutras on which all the Major Vedanta Philosophical Schools are established (vedanta)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta. Karma Yoga Suits you, while Bhakti Yoga Marga (Path)is best path.