# Is applying sindoor compulsory after marriage?

Tags: culture, marriage, tradition, tilak

Is applying sindoor after marriage mandatory or just a choice? Do Hindu scripture say anything about applying sindoor after marriage?

Comment: Neccessary or not, it depends on reason of using it. If the reason is valid enough to use then we have to use it else ignore. So your actual question should be like: Why women use sindhoor after marriage?

Comment: Related: [Why Hindus wear red tilak and sandal wood tilak on foreheads?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/163/1049)

Comment: one simple reason if you're not very religious - is to easily declare to the world that you're a married woman, so that other men treat you with respect and distance. If people didn't know whether you were married just by looking at your face, they could behave inappropriately.

Answer (score 5):

The book [Dharma Bindu](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf) quotes Veda Vyasa as follows:

> Vyasa Maharshi gave the instructions as follows:
>
> **Haridraamkumkumamchaiva sindhuram kajjalam tathaa**,
>  Kurpaanakam
>   cha taambolam mangalaabharanam shubham|
>  Kesha samskaara kabari
>   kara karnaad bhushanam,
>  Bhartur aayushyami -cchanti dooshayenna
>   Pativrataa|
>  Praatah kaaletu yaa naari dadyaadarghyam
>   vivasvate,
>  Sapta janmaani vaidhavyaam saa naari naiva pashyati|
>
> ..................
>
> Those women who are interested in the longevity of their husbands
>   should not to ignore the high significance of turmeric powder,
>   kumkuma, eyetex, vastra, jewellery like ear studs, bangles, necklaces
>   etc. As at the early mornings, women offering Arghya or water for
>   worshipping Surya Deva would avoiod widow hood for seven births ahead!

So, scriptures definitely talk about the importance that Sindhoor or Kumkuma has in a married Hindu woman's life.