# What is the significance of applying chandan on forehead?

Tags: belief, tilak

What is the significance of chandan application on forehead for Hindus? I have been told my mom not to apply Chandan and I don’t understand the reason.need help

Comment: Probably you can find your answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/163/why-hindus-wear-red-tilak-and-sandal-wood-tilak-on-foreheads

Comment: No I looked through it does not tell me why I should not apply chandan tilak

Comment: Not applying is a personal choice. There are so many things we should be doing as said in the scriptures but not doing them is ones personal choice, nobody can force you.

Comment: I just want to know what scriptures say about it and post that I can feel free to decide if I want to follow or not

Comment: Some smart people (I mean who think they are smart) have even closed the question without even understanding it... come on guys go get a life

Comment: If you are smart enough than those smart people, first search the site first and ask the question. You should frame the question properly. Don't blame others when you give a vague title. The question which you are asking is already asked. Questions make duplicates here not the answers. Visit [ask] and  go [edit] your question how it is different than blaming others.  Question is not closed. It is put 'on hold'. There is a difference.

Comment: Yes I am smart and have read the other question it does not answer why a sandalwood tilak should not be applied if you are smart enough then answer it else just ignore instead of marking it as duplicate

Comment: But that is what we are trying to convey that the question has already been answered where it says why it should be applied, if you don't apply it won't make any difference to anyone, you will still live no? Such things comes into picture when you are fully devoted and committed on spiritual journey, else whether you do it or not hardly matters.

Comment: I am very devoted and don’t want to do anything wrong which upsets some god or is spiritually not inclined. Please understand my reason to ask is to know that I am not doing anything wrong by applying chandan.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in applying a tilak, until unless your body is allergic to it. Don't we apply different oil/creams etc on our hair and body? Chandan isn't a chemical product.

Comment: @RahulK Did u ask ur mom why she is asking u not to?

Comment: She is no more so I can’t ask her I was young when she told me

Comment: Ok ..@RahulK...